# Two-dimensional hash map: A matrix where row and column types are pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, matrix

I'm looking for a two-dimensional hash map where the row and column indexes are pointers. I.e., instead of unsigned, consecutive integers being the row and column indexes, I require them to be pointers.

I do not care about insertion performance or its size in memory, but I do need fast lookup and iteration.

A basic interface could look like:

```
template<typename Key, typename Value>
class pointer_matrix
{
public:
    iterator insert(Key const& row, Key const& column, Value& value);
    Value& at(Key const& row, Key const& column);
    row_iterator row(Key const& row);
    column_iterator column(Key const& column);
};
```

This interface would allow me two types of lookups:

- Given two keys, I can identify the corresponding value object: `(Key, Key) => Value`
- Given just one key, I can iterate over a number of value objects; this vector of value objects represents either the row or the column, depending on the lookup: `Key => (Value, Value, ...)`

It is basically a "table" where both the column and the row headers are pointers, instead of consecutive integers starting at 0.

Searching Google for "pointer matrix" or "hash matrix" turns up information about simple `my_type**` matrixes, which is definitely *not* what I need.

Does a container like that exist? If not: What would be the tools sensible to build such a container?

Comment: How about `std::map`?

Comment: In your example interface, do you mean that `Key` must be a "any hashable type"? (And you know that "unsigned, consecutive integers" are included in that "hashable" requirement) Can you please edit your question to include an example how the `pointer_matrix` could be used? Or at least include a use-case?

Comment: Anyway, if you want anything hashable as key, why not use [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) as underlying container?

Comment: @ZDF, @Joachim Pileborg: I'm sorry, I don't see how `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` can be the whole solution. These two classes map `Key => Value`, whereas I require `(Key, Key) => Value` as well as `Key => (Value, Value, ...)` for both columns and rows. I realize that, as soon as one creates such a container for pointers, any hashable type can be used for column and row types.

Comment: Have you thought of a map of maps? E.g. `std::unordered_map<Key, std::unordered_map<Key, Value>>`

Comment: You seem to be looking for a two dimensional map. Usually you'd just make a map of maps, `std::unordered_map<key, std::unordered_map<key, value>>`, and so-on to get further dimensions of maps. It is not however a matrix ( e.g. what would be its determinant?  ) so searching for matrix implementations probably doesn't help.

Comment: @PeteKirkham: Thanks for the hint wrt the term matrix, I've changed the title of my question accordingly. Generally, a map-of-maps would help my with my `(Key, Key) => Value` lookup, but I don't see how I can iterate over rows and columns then. I can still wrap three containers (`map<Key, map<Key, Value>>` and two `map<Key, vector<Value>>`), but it seems that people might already have throught of a better solution.

Comment: You can iterate over them using iterators.

Comment: I have read again your question. From this: _"a matrix where the row and column indexes are pointers"_, it results that what you want is to associate some value with two pointers, not with the values these pointers are pointing. Are you sure? It does not sound right.

Comment: if you **must** have both row and column iteration, you probably have to roll your own, and one of those will be slooow

Comment: @ZDF: Yes, exactly, I want a lookup based on two pointers, i.e., `(K*, K*) => V`, and `K* => (V, V, ...)`. (The asterisk is added for emphasis.) Again, I realize that once one has a two-dimensional hashmap that works with pointers as key types, any type one can compute an hash for is usable. But right now, I want to look up one object given two indexing pointers, and I also want to look up a row (and a column) of objects given just one pointer. It really is "just" a table where the column/row headers are pointers.

Comment: I do not know any off the shelf class to meet your requirements. I guess that you will have to build it yourself using some sort of mapping classes.

Comment: have a look at http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0ae5c70bfaa83922

Comment: @sp2danny: Care to post the link as an answer? It looks very much like what I need... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe is a hash table of hash tables. That is, every bucket is a small hash table with (conceptually) a different hash function. A different size may serve as a different hash function if you do % size.

I guess you're trying to achieve some sort of perfect hashing, and this is one of the ways there. You can read about it in wikipedia.

If your interest is in the  real-world (as opposed to academic) I'd test this against normal hashing, with linked list buckets.
The lookup performance of perfect hashes is not guaranteed to be any better.

Answer (score -1):

Use a multimap (MM) >.

When you add a value , you must also insert > and >.

When inserting, , you must search for key1, if found you insert  in the map insert returned as a value (MM_iter->second).
Otherwise you create a map with  and insert it in MM.

This way, if you search a unique key, return all the values in the map returned by MM.find(key);
if you make a search using 2 keys, MM.find(key1).find(key2).

Comment: if you do a MM.find(key1), how is the result different depending on if you search for row or column? some code examples might clarify further

Comment: I supposed that key1 and 2 can be inverted.
The question says "Given just one key, I can iterate over a number of value objects; this vector of value objects represents either the row or the column, depending on the lookup: Key => (Value, Value, ...)"
If you want to segregate rows from columns, you must use 2 MM and only insert/request in one of them (about this, the question is ambiguous to me...)

Comment: Maps are trees so lookup time is logarithmic. Hashes lookup in const time.